# Outlook remembers account settings even if account is deleted

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

In my Outlook 2007, I had configured a mail account to download mails from my Yahoo Business Mail account. I had set up my folder subscriptions for only a few folders, and in Send Receive Groups, I had configured to download only message headers.

Later, after downloading message headers, when I marked a few messages for full download, they were not getting downloaded. So I tried to remove the account and add it again.

But when I add the same account again, Outlook surprisingly remembers the folder subscriptions, even though I had deleted the previous account. Also the new account is by default configured to download only message headers.

I am curious to know where does Outlook store account settings, and why it does not delete them when an account is removed, and importantly, how to delete all settings associated with a mail account?

I also checked the keys in the registry, but they are all in binary format, and I am not sure which of them can be deleted safely after deleting email account.

Comment: This information is stored in the registry.  You should be able to change the settings even after the account is created.

Comment: I want to know how to permanently delete the settings.

Answer (score 0):

That's because Outlook stores all account configuration in a file called Outlook.OST.

To Remove the file make sure you can see file extensions and go to the following explorer path :

- Windows 7/Vista: C:\users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook
- Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook